# Comparing a hashes value against array in order

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, rspec

If I have the following hash and array

```
hash  = {'i' => 'i', 'av' => 'av', 'deviceName' => 'Genymotionvbox86p'}
array = ['i', 'av', 'Genymotionvbox86p']
```

How could I compare that each item in the array matches the hashes value in the same order

So far I have

```
array.each do |value|
  hash.each do |k, v|
    expect(v).to eq(value), "expected #{k} to equal #{v}, instead got #{value}"
  end
end
```

This is failing as I get

```
expected av to equal av, instead got i (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I'm not quite there yet and imagine that a loop within a loop is not the best thing to do either?

I would like to know how to efficiently approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would really want to compare item-by-item, you rightfully noticed that a loop within a loop is not the way to go. You need a single loop to iterate both structures.

For that, you can, for example, use `zip`, to combine hash and array:

```
hash.zip(array).each do |(hash_key, hash_value), array_item|
  expect(hash_value).to eq array_item
end
```

or you can resort to using an index:

```
hash.each_with_index do |(k, v), i|
  expect(v).to eq array[i]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason this fails is because you compare every array value with every hash value. To solve this, you can take advantage of the fact that two arrays arrays are equal if all their values in order are equal:

```
expect(array).to eq hash.values
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could I compare that each item in the array matches the hashes
>   value in the same order

how about this?

```
> array == hash.values
#=> true 
>  array = ["i", "Genymotionvbox86p", "av"] # change the order
> array == hash.values
#=> false
```